# Can I cut the bottom part of this let-in brace

Tags: remodeling

I'd like to remove a wall between the kitchen and living room. I also want to remove the closet and cabinets. While removing the drywall I found what appears to be a Let-in brace. The wall with the brace is a partial exterior partial interior wall. The wall starts outside the front door and goes all the way to the cabinets. I want to remove the interior portion right where the door starts. The brace starts at the top of the wall on the exterior portion of the wall and goes to the floor at an angle to the interior portion of the wall. If I remove all the interior portion of the wall I'd have to remove the bottom half of the brace. Can I do this without any other modifications?

The home is a single story on slab in CA with trussed roof.
[image: Floor Plan]
[image: Brace]

Comment: Given location, you might need to consult a seismic engineer. I assume that's why it's there.

Comment: You are correct. It's for shear brace for wind and earthquake. Oh well. I guess my island will be a peninsula instead.